# Is it possible to forcefully crash a MySQL Innodb table?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I want to test few things and need a Innodb corrupted table. 
In MyISAM if we run repair table and kill in the middle then it will corrupt the table but how to forcefully corrupt a Innodb small table.

Also the table is very small, if i try to run alter, analyze or anything I didn't get a chance to kill the command in middle..

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This might be better for SuperUser.com

Comment: ok will post there as well..

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com might be even better. Don't post multiple times, flag the question and ask the mods to move it.

Comment: @barmar.  ok thanks..

Comment: just edit it with a hex editor and put in some garbage

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to corrupt InnoDB tablespace.

- Disable double write buffer and kill mysqld during write intensive workload. The double write prevents partially written pages. If you disable it there is a chance a page will be half written and hence corrupt.
- Write garbage to a page with a hex editor. If *.ibd/ibdata1 isn't large you can do that with `bvi`. Search for strings `infimum` or `supremum` to find pages with user data. Overwrite space before a record with zeroes. It'll make InnoDB scream.

Comment: How to disable double write buffer?